# A macOS getaddrinfo() bug related to the use of AI_V4MAPPED?

Tags: linux, macos, ipv6, ipv4, getaddrinfo

I noticed a strange behaviour of the simple program `showip.c` (https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/showip.c) when run on Linux (3.13.0) and macOS (10.15.7)
The same program gives two different results (obviously I am not referring to the different IPv4 addresses):

```
Linux -> ./showip www.google.com
IP addresses for www.google.com:

  IPv4: 216.58.206.36
  IPv6: 2a00:1450:4002:800::2004
Linux ->
```

And on macOS:

```
macOS -> ./showip www.google.com
IP addresses for www.google.com:

  IPv4: 142.250.180.100
macOS ->
```

However, when the line

```
hints.ai_flags |= AI_V4MAPPED;
```

is added in the definition of hints of the macOS version, also macOS prints the IPv6 address.
That is surprising and, moreover, I didn’t understand this to be the semantic of AI_V4MAPPED. A macOS bug?

Code:

```
/*
** showip.c -- show IP addresses for a host given on the command line
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    int status;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: showip hostname\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return 2;
    }

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for(p = res;p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void *addr;
        char *ipver;

        // get the pointer to the address itself,
        // different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) { // IPv4
            struct sockaddr_in *ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        } else { // IPv6
            struct sockaddr_in6 *ipv6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        // convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res); // free the linked list

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It also works if you use `AI_ALL`

Comment: Which is surprising, because the documentation says this is ignored when `AI_V4MAPPED` is not set. It sounds like bugs.

Comment: I'm testing on MacOS 10.13.

Comment: Do you have IPv6 enabled in your Network preferences?

Comment: I don't see DHCP IPv6 address assignments in macOS System Preferences. But an IPv6 address is reported by ifconfig on the Ethernet interface.

Comment: It's the same for me. I think it's because I have IPv6 disabled on my router.